# How to determine if a specific class in html exists, with Html Agilty Pack in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I want to know if a specific product by numbers exists in a web page. That page has a search bar, I determined that html class "product-thumb" appears only when search result is TRUE. So i wanna use that class as an example of TRUE and FALSE in IF statement. I'm using html agilty pack to do this task, here is a code what I already have but it doesn't work, always returns FALSE. I googled a lot, can't find proper solution yet, and that's why I left not working code here. I have string "url" like this because I will list many numbers like this to check for each product, preperations for a big loop, but still can't make this test code work. Thanks in advance.

```
        string url = "90551";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        string s = "http://examplewebpage" + url;
        doc = web.Load(s);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        if (doc.DocumentNode.HasClass("//*[@class=\"product-thumb") == true)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = url + " Yes";
        }
        else
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = url + " No";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just search for any item containing 'product-thumb' class

```
var containsProductThumb = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants()
    .Any( d => 
        d.Attributes.Contains("class")
        &&
        d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("product-thumb")
    );
if (containsProductThumb)
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = url + " Yes";
else
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = url + " No";
```